# What is the proper location for code classes (POCO, Models, etc.) in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class, asp.net-mvc-5, architecture, visual-studio-2019

I'm getting started with MVC, and I'm following [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rickandy/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views).

In it, we find that the `Blog` type is contained in the `Controller`'s class file, in the `Mvc3ViewDemo.Controllers` namespace. This is a bit of a no-no in design methodology, as each class should be kept in its own file. (At least that's my particular convention.)

But when we move it out to its own file—even using the same namespace—the Controller can no longer see it:

[image]

(In VB.NET, the top-level namespace `Mvc3ViewDemo` is specified at the project level.)

I tried putting the file in both `App_Code` and the project root:

```
Namespace Controllers
  Public Class Blog
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Url As String
  End Class
End Namespace
```

The view can see it:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of Controllers.Blog)

@Code
  ViewData("Title") = "Blog"
End Code

<h2>BLOG</h2>

<ul>
  @For Each oBlog In Model
    @<li><a href="@oBlog.Url">@oBlog.Name</a></li>
  Next
</ul>
```

[image]

...but the Controller can't.

If we put it in the `Models` folder, neither the Controller nor the View can see it.

Horror of horrors! Is MVC going to force me to put all of my classes in the same files as my controllers? What do we do when we need a model that's used by two or more controllers?

**--EDIT--**

In addition, I'm unable to add an `Imports` (`using`) statement for the target namespace to the Controller class file:

[image: Models.Blog]
[image: Bad Imports statement]
[image: Refactor suggestion]

Comment: You just have to add a using statement where the class is required, then you can have it wherever you need it

Comment: Pardon me, I neglected to mention that that's one of the first things I tried (I knew I was forgetting something). I've updated my question. This is an odd one. It should 'just work.'

Comment: It was the file's build action. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the `Blog` class file's Build Action was set to `Content`. Apparently this is the default action for new code files created under `App_Code`, which is why I missed it. It was right under my nose the whole time.

I set it to `Compile` and now everything works as expected.

**--EDIT--**

I've filed a bug report which may be reviewed [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1167565/new-classes-added-to-app-code-receive-a-build-acti.html).